# htaccess Redirect all except the specified URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Cannot use (!) reverse operation, a redirect URL (http://ssvwv.com) will appear:

```
/1/3/ktrb
```

Will not display (index.html)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/1\/(?:1|2|3)\/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ssvwv.com/ [L,R=302,NE]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:index\.html|1/[1-3]/.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://ssvwv.com/ [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

Issue is that last rule is rewriting to `/index.html` and when `mod_rewrite` loops again URI becomes `/index.html` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/1\/(?:1|2|3)\/.*$` returns true thus redirecting to `http://ssvwv.com/`. That's why you need to skip `/index.html` from first rule as well.